# Subset a dataframe within shiny reactive structure

Tags: r, shiny

I am unable to subset a dataframe within a reactive shiny structure and display it as a table. If I try to just display the dataframe, I am able to but unable to subset and display. I believe its got to do something with the way `input$` is used.

Please help, I quite new to shiny

**Dataset**

```
dput(b)
structure(list(Date = c("1-Jan", "2-Jan", "3-Jan"), Month = c("Jan", 
"Jan", "Jan"), Days = c("Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), A = c(30712L, 26842L, 
21640L), B = c(26505L, 25906L, 22929L), C = c(22128L, 26814L, 
22091L), D = c(30994L, 23935L, 20048L), E = c("38%", "51%", "37%"
), F = c(71L, 70L, 71L), G = c(91L, 114L, 104L), H = c(77L, 98L, 
91L), I = c(-4621L, -463L, 291L), J = c("-32.00%", "-3.30%", 
"2.00%")), .Names = c("Date", "Month", "Days", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(                  
  sidebarLayout(   
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "col", label = "Columns",choices = colnames(b[4:8]),selected = colnames(b[4]))),

    mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")))))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

b<-read.csv("newb.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datum<-reactive({
    d<-b[,input$col]
    return(d)
  })

  output$table<-renderDataTable({datum()})

 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are selecting only one column of the `b` data frame. The result of this subsetting is a vector, not a data frame, so `renderDataTable` cannot render it.

You can convert the vector to a data frame in your reactive expression:

```
  datum<-reactive({
    d <- b[,input$col]
    d <- as.data.frame(d)
    colnames(d) <- input$col
    d
  })
```

An easier solution using @docendo discimus's comment:

```
datum<-reactive({ d<-b[,input$col,drop=FALSE] 
d })
```

Comment: Or `b[ , input$col, drop = FALSE]` maybe?

Comment: I was just looking for: `datum<-reactive({
    d<-b[,input$col,drop=FALSE]
    d<-as.data.frame(d)
    })`
  It worked thanks.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, you comment helped me get `headers`

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz, you should only need `datum<-reactive({ b[, input$col, drop = FALSE]})`

Comment: @docendodiscimus, yes it did

Comment: @docendodiscimus and Nice--  pls could you guys look at this as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251438/unable-to-use-reactive-element-in-my-shiny-app